# how can I inject request in database that is calculating?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm facing an issue where I'm sure that there is an sql injection (in my own website) and I'm confirming that by sqlmap.
the server/database-server calculate an arithmetic operation and put it in the body of the page example if I do: http://url?parameter=200-1 in the body he returns the result for parameter=199, and if i do http://url?parameter=100/2 it returns the results for parameter=50.
whith some research I can do http://url?parameter=10-(case when 1 = 2 then 1 else 2 end) and it returns the reults for parameter=8 in this case. I would like to know if it is possible to do an INSERT ?
thank you.

Comment: That depends on your server side code as well.

Comment: In the URL it is also possible to do this: http://url?parameter=1 or parameter=2 and it returns the results for the two at the same time. I'm absolutely sure that it is simple.. but I can't get it right now.

Comment: Yeah, but that example still uses select. To use insert, you need to add a new sql statement (this may be prevented by the mysql api you use) or comment out the previous section of the code - that's not simple either.